# Force loopback traffic to exit interface

Tags: windows, networking

Here's what I'm trying to do:

System: Windows 10

VPN TUN NIC with IP 10.2.3.4

I have a service listening on 10.2.3.4:567, and I would like to establish a connection to this service from the same machine. However, I would like the traffic to exit the network interface instead of being sent through the software loopback. Basically, I want the traffic to exit the VPN adapter to the VPN server, and be routed back to me.

Comment: Using an IP address other than `localhost` should do that. Accessing `10.2.3.4:567` will go through the router. Going through the internet requires a compatible router, if that's your request.

Comment: @harrymc that's not true, I have confirmed via packet captures that 10.2.3.4:567 traffic does not exit the interface

Comment: Which interface? The internet?

Comment: @RichardHum My first instinct is that this is not possible without really awful hacky workarounds. Could you share why you want to do this?

Comment: @Karu it's for a proof of concept exploit I'm working on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is probably a bad idea and will probably break things in subtle ways, but it should be technically possible.**

First, we can verify that Windows does not send traffic destined for the configured IP out of the local system by looking at Wireshark. On my system, my IP is `192.168.88.100` and my router / default gateway is `192.168.88.1`. If I run `ping 192.168.88.100` while filtering Wireshark traffic for `ip.dst == 192.168.88.100 && ip.proto == ICMP`, we see no results returned.

[image: Wireshark output]

What we can do is to add a route that will send all traffic from your system destined for `10.2.3.4` to whatever the default gateway for your VPN network is. Open an administrator command prompt and look at the output of `route print`. Odds are, you'll see something in your route table like this:

`192.168.88.100  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.88.100    281`

This means all traffic destined for `192.168.88.100` is to be handled by `192.168.88.100`. There's our software loopback! The packets never actually go out the interface, so Wireshark doesn't see them.

So what happens if I explicitly add a route saying traffic destined for `192.168.88.100` should instead be handled by my router at `192.168.88.1`?

The command is `route add (destination) mask (netmask) (router)`

So I do `route add 192.168.88.100 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.88.1` and retry my ping...

[image: Wireshark output after the route command]

There we go. The traffic is now demonstrably hitting the router at `192.168.88.1` - in fact, it's replying with an ICMP redirect packet telling my system "hey, this is a non-optimal route".

We can be doubly sure because the IMCP reply packet, even though it has a source and destination of `192.168.88.100`, the MAC address on the reply packet is from a different MAC:

`Src: HewlettP_93:61:44 (ac:16:2d:93:61:44), Dst: ASUSTekC_68:58:db (2c:4d:54:68:58:db)` (my router has an HP NIC).

So, for whatever you're doing here, figure out what the default gateway is for your VPN connection, and sub in the appropriate IP addresses in the `route add` command.